# Windows phone application pre-release QR code

Tags: windows-phone-7

As i remember, after the first submission, they provide a QR code for developers. 
Is it possible to get a QR code after submitting an update (to share it to testers)?

[Here](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2011/04/15/mango-adds-beta-and-private-marketplaces-to-windows-phone-7-and-neglects-enterprise/) is said something about Beta stage

Comment: If they gave a QR code after the first update, you can re-use it: the URL does not change when you update the app

Comment: @KooKiz But it was for a 1 version, which is published now. And i'd like to get a new QR code for the version 2, which i just submitted.

Also, it was some time ago, i'm not sure if i'd be able to find it. Is there any way to renew it?

Comment: When you submit an update, you overwrite the old version. Version 1 won't exist anymore, users will only be able to download version 2, by using the same link. Or maybe you submitted your version 2 as a brand new app rather than an update? In any case, all you need is the marketplace link, which has been sent to you after you submitted the app (or you can find it on the devcenter). From there, it's just a matter of finding a website that allows you to generate a QR code from that URL.

Comment: @KooKiz Yep, i submitted version 2 as update. But now, i should wait for certification, before it will appear on the market. But when i submited version 1, i got a private link (QR) right after submission, before app being published.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember ever getting a QR code after a submission, so I can't really tell. But generating a QR code is trivial. Just search "QR code generator" on Google and pick the one that strikes your fancy.

Comment: @KooKiz. The problem is: that QR code would direct to my app on the store. For now, i have version 1 already published, and market link would lead there. What i want - is to have a QR code to unsubmitted app, which is now in the certification process, so i can share it among testers before app would be available on the market.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37191/discussion-between-vitalii-vasylenko-and-kookiz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okaaay, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it is. But testers should have dev accounts...

Comment: Betatesters don't need a dev account. They just need a live account